# Вывод на русском языке

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры-данных

Изначальная проблема была решена. Как сделать корректный вывод на русском языке?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>

struct challenge
{
    char country[50];
    char team[40];
    char name[40];
    int number;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
} players[100];

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    challenge players[100];
    int i, j, k, teamage = 0, minTA = 100, counti = 0;

    std::cout << "Введите количество участников: ";
    std::cin >> k;

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\nВведите название страны: ";
        std::cin >> players[i].country;

        std::cout << "Введите название команды: ";
        std::cin >> players[i].team;

        std::cout << "Введите ФИО участника: ";
        std::cin >> players[i].name;

        std::cout << "Введите игровой номер участника: ";
        std::cin >> players[i].number;

        std::cout << "Введите возраст участника: ";
        std::cin >> players[i].age;

        std::cout << "Введите рост участника: ";
        std::cin >> players[i].height;

        std::cout << "Введите вес участника: ";
        std::cin >> players[i].weight;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < k - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < k; j++)
            if (strcmp(players[i].team, players[j].team) == 0)
                teamage += players[j].age;
        if (minTA > teamage)
        {
            counti = i;
            minTA = teamage;
        }
        teamage = 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Самая молодая команда - " << players[counti].team << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::setw(15) << "Страна" << std::setw(15) << "ФИО" << std::setw(15) << "Игровой номер" << std::setw(15) << "Возраст" << std::setw(15) << "Рост" << std::setw(15) << "Вес" << std::endl;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(players[i].team, players[counti].team) == 0)
            std::cout << std::setw(15) << players[i].country << std::setw(15) << players[i].name << std::setw(15) << players[i].number << std::setw(15) << players[i].age << std::setw(15) << players[i].height << std::setw(15) << players[i].weight << std::endl;
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Вывод]

Comment: У вас немного странный алгоритм поиска минимального возраста, я думаю можно уложиться в один цикл и проблема отпадет сама собой, а так код выглядит запутанно и непонятно что вы хотели им вообще сделать

Comment: Не подскажете как именно в 1 цикл?

Comment: К тому же, вы сами вводите возраст команд 10, 19 и 10, вот и получили нулевой элемент - первая самая молодая команда. Что не так в результате? Или приведите пример, где будет выводиться неправильный результат

Comment: Вводится информация об участниках, в моём вводе 1 и 3 участники в одной команде, следовательно возраст на команду это 20 лет. Мне нужна самая молодая именно команда

Comment: А, тогда ваша ошибка вот в чем: строки нельзя сравнивать оператором равенства в С++. Для этого есть метод strcmp, который вернет 0 если строки равны. Попробуйте исправить это для начала тогда.

Comment: Попробуй совет [отсюда](https://nicknixer.ru/programmirovanie/russkie-simvolybukvy-pri-vvodevyvode-v-konsol-na-c/)

Comment: У вас ввод некорректный. `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` тоже не к месту